# Can derived columns in ADF Dataflow be used to map without creating duplicate columns?

Tags: azure-data-factory, derived-column

I'm trying to change column names using derived columns. I'm able to do this with one mapping per column but after that I get a 'Duplicate Column' problem.

Can this be done with derived columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got past this by making multiple Derived Columns and doing a nested mapping type thing.